# Get specific value from array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel. Here is my array -

> [{"emp_id":1,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21
>   12:00:00"},{"emp_id":2,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21
>   12:00:00"},{"emp_id":3,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21
>   12:00:00"},{"emp_id":4,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21
>   12:00:00"},{"emp_id":6,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21
>   12:00:00"},{"emp_id":7,"shift":"first","status":"Present","is_unpaid":0,"start":"2018-03-21
>   08:00:00","end":"2018-03-21 12:00:00"}]

And this is my array output code -

```
if(empty($employee->emp_record) ){
            $sheet  = array();
        }else{
            $sheet = unserialize($employee->emp_record);
        }

        return $sheet;
```

I want to get value of emp_id and show in the view. When I use `return $sheet->emp_id;`

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   This error happened.

Comment: You have multiple records and each one contains an `emp_id` so you need to choose which one to return or access like this `return $sheet[0]->emp_id;`

Comment: what's the output of:- `var_export($sheet);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first record only, you need to use:-

```
return $sheet[0]->emp_id;
```

But if you want all, then apply a loop like below:-

```
foreach($sheet as $shet){
  echo $shet->emp_id;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/995586

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pluck()` function to get the first record of an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want all, then apply a loop like below:-

```
    $sheet = [];
    if(!empty($employee->emp_record) ){
        foreach($sheet as $shet){
            $sheet[] = [
               "emp_id" => $shet->emp_id
               //.....rest data set
            ];
        }
    }
    return $sheet;
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  (even if you see other users doing it)  What new value does your answer bring to this page?  Why should researchers read/use your advice?